# Why I cant' defrag my computer?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

I tried to stard defrag in many way (start menu, run dialog and so on), and never would start. So I tried trough command line and what I get when I run *defrag* command is:

```
Parameter is not correct (0x80070057)
```

followed by the usual description and information about the command. What problem is this? I've tried to change the decimal separator and to launch this [fixit](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9777176) but the error is still there. Any ideas?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982736/en `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\System` 
`CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo` DWORD 1

Comment: How much free space is there on the drive?

Comment: @jmreicha Almost 217GB on 283GB total.

Comment: @STTR As I wrote, I've already tried with those methods and nothing changed.

Comment: Shot in the dark here but have you tried chkdsk?

Comment: Could you post the actual command you used? The one that gives the error message. Also, what happens when you try graphically? You said it did not work. How? Any error messages?

Comment: @terdon when I try graphically nothing happen. Prompt of MS-DOS appear for just half second (probably will print the same error message).

Comment: OK, what command did you use to launch the defrag from the command line? We cannot know if you have an error unless we see the actual command. Also, why do you want to defrag? It is almost certainly unneeded.

Comment: @terdon I tried with defrag, defrag c:, defrag c: /a /v and almost every example provided by the command's manual. Cause computer is quite slow, and I would try an ancient medicine to speed him up.

Comment: @jmreicha Yes i've tried to launch chkdsk and no error was on it. I'm completly without any idea...

Comment: Are you experiencing any other strange symptoms on this machine?

Comment: @jmreicha it's slow, sometimes get block, sometimes when i watch a movie the computer suddenly shut down...

Comment: @Mariano I would suggest testing out the hardware, try testing the drive with this: http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT